# How to inherit Java-EE API for Webapps in Maven?

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, dependency-management

My project has the following structure with multiple jars and wars:

```
root (pom)
+--core (jar)
+--webapp (jar)
+--childgroup (pom)
   +--actual-web-application (war)
   +--some-library (jar)
+--othergroup (pom)
   +--another-web-application (war)
```

Where actual-web-application depends on webapp which depends on core. Ideally, I would like to specify the Java EE dependency only in the webapp module and let the actual-web-application inherit it. But because it's a provided dependency, this doesn't work and I have to manually add dependencies for provided stuff like Java EE, jax-rs etc. in every web application.

Is there any way, with dependencyManagement for example, to let actual-web-application inherit the javaee-api from the webapp?

What I've tried, in webapp's pom.xml:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

And in actual-web-application's pom.xml:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

However, it complies about the version so it seems like it's still not carrying over the dependency from webapp's pom.xml.

Comment: `<scope>provided</scope>`  is not transitive.

Comment: I know, but I was wondering if there is a workaround for this.

Comment: Simple answer no. The scope provided has a meaning. The only `workaround` is not to use `provided` which is simply wrong.

Comment: Okay, I'm a bit sad that every webapp has to explicitly specify the APIs it wants to use and that there is no inheritance for provided libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Put `<scope>provided</scope>` into dependencyManagement also

Answer (score 0):

Provided dependencies are inherited just as any other dependency would be.

parent pom.xml:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

child pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And the child's dependency tree:

```
--- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ child ---
com.iei.web:child:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT
\- javax:javaee-api:jar:7.0:provided
   \- com.sun.mail:javax.mail:jar:1.5.0:provided
       \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:provided
```

If you are trying to avoid explicitly defining dependencies in the child at all, then you would of course have to move it out of `dependencyManagement` in the parent and make it a direct dependency, assuming you want every child module to inherit it.

[Dependency Management](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Management)

Comment: I guess my problem is that the dependency is in a sibling project, but not in the dependencyManagement of the direct parent, is that correct?

Comment: Ah yes, I had misread that part of your hierarchy. The sibling dependency will only be brought over if actual-web-app explicitly depends on webapp and it comes through transitively.